# core data search issue iOS 5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Using core data, data is being fetched properly and shown properly, issue is with the search that it does not filter the results, whatever I type in the search bar, it does show the same table view with same data in the filtered results..

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if (context == nil) 
    { 
        context = [(VektorAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext]; 
    }    
    app = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

     [self getData];

    // create a filtered list that will contain products for the search results table.

    filteredListItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[self.plateNumbers count]];

    // restore search settings if they were saved in didReceiveMemoryWarning.
    if (self.savedSearchTerm){
        [self.searchDisplayController setActive:self.searchWasActive];
        [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar setSelectedScopeButtonIndex:self.savedScopeButtonIndex];
        [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar setText:savedSearchTerm];

    self.savedSearchTerm = nil;
    }
}
```

Fetching data from core data:

```
-(void)getData {

NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Favouritesdata" inManagedObjectContext:context];

NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

[request setFetchBatchSize:20];

[request setEntity:entity];

NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"licenseplate" ascending:NO];

NSArray *newArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:sort, nil];

[request setSortDescriptors:newArray];

NSLog(@"newArray: %@", newArray);

NSError *error;

results = [[context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];

plateNumbers = [results valueForKey:@"licenseplate"];

NSLog(@"plateNumbers: %@", plateNumbers);

[self setLicensePlateArray:results];

[self.favouritesTable reloadData];

}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
if (tableView == favouritesTable) {
    return [licensePlateArray count];
} else { // handle search results table view
    return [filteredListItems count];
    }      
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

if (tableView == favouritesTable) {
    cellValue = [licensePlateArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
} else { // handle search results table view
    cellValue = [filteredListItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"vlCell";

VehicleListCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {

    NSLog(@"Cell Created");

    NSArray *nibObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"VehicleListCell" owner:nil options:nil];

    for (id currentObject in nibObjects) {
        if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[VehicleListCell class]]) {
            cell = (VehicleListCell *)currentObject;
        }
    }
    NSInteger cellVal = indexPath.row;

    NSLog(@"indexPath.row: %i", cellVal);

    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *pressRecongnizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tableCellPressed:)];
    pressRecongnizer.delegate = self;
    pressRecongnizer.minimumPressDuration = 0.5f;
    [cell addGestureRecognizer:pressRecongnizer];
    [pressRecongnizer release];
}

cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10];

Favouritesdata *favdata = [results objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

cell.licPlate.text = [favdata licenseplate];

NSLog(@"cellvalue for cellforRow: %@", cell.licPlate.text);

return cell;
}
```

Search bar implementation:

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{       
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate 
                                    predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@",
                                    searchText];

    self.filteredListItems = [self.plateNumbers filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];

}

- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString {
   /* [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString scope:
     [[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles] objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];
    */

    if ([[searchString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] length])
        self.favouritesTable = controller.searchResultsTableView;

    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchScope:(NSInteger)searchOption {
    [self filterContentForSearchText:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar text] scope:
     [[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles] objectAtIndex:searchOption]];
    return YES;
}
```

How to resolve this issue ?

Comment: you are missing to set a NSPredicate for you Request

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFetching.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002484-SW1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make code clear before and define every methods, you are just setting predicate, not firing query for it.

just make separate method and just pass search text as parameter to that method for predicate and fire fetch query then reload table.

Comment: but I am not getting where to set predicate, in filterContentForSearchText: there is already a predicate is set.